# Javascript - Function Variable to use in another variable

Tags: javascript

I want to use a function's variable value to build a variable in the function.

Here's what I got so far:

```
function foo(1a, 1b) {
 var money = document.myform.1b;
}
```

So basically, if I pass in `foo(aaa, bbb)`, I would like the variable money to be:

> var money = document.myform.bbb;

Comment: Take note that `1a` and `1b` are not valid [Identifiers](http://asenbozhilov.com/articles/identifiers-en.html#identifier_start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.myform[bbb]` if bbb is a string.
Which effect are you after?

1

```
var bbb="variablename";
var money = document.myform.bbb
```

or 2

```
var bbb="variablename";
var money=document.myform.variablename
```

Comment: document.myform[bbb] worked! I'm using this to make dynamic selects.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(a, b) {
  var money = document.myform[b];
}
```

Also, I don't believe js vars can begin with a number.

Answer (score -1):

var money = document.getElementById(1b);

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/getelementbyid-form.htm